# Ошибка при компиляции c# проекта

Tags: c#, компиляция

Скачал себе visual studio для мака, создал проект под с#, решил запустить а оно выдает ошибку:
Invalid 'cwd' value '/Users/s.k./Documents/Programming/c#/projects/test/test'. The system cannot find the path specified.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

[image: Ето пример кода, который я питаюсь запустить. Код автоматически добавлен после создание проекта]
Ето пример кода, который я питаюсь запустить. Код автоматически добавлен после создание проекта

[image: То что происходит при попытке компиляции кода]
То что происходит при попытке компиляции кода

Comment: Предлагаете без вашего кода погадать о вашей проблеме?

Comment: проблема не с кодом а с чем то другим. потому что весь код который там есть ето Hello world

Comment: Вы можете со мной спорить и ждать чуда, а можете добавить код в вопрос. А лучше добавить в вопрос все, что касается вопроса, включая минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Сделал, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема из за точки в конце имени учетной записи.
Такая же проблема встречается здесь: [учетка с точкой](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155731/aspnet-core-20-cant-rundebug-invalid-cwd.html)

Проверьте указанный путь `cwd`.
Все ли каталоги существуют: /Users/s.k./Documents/Programming/c#/projects/test/test

Если нет, попробуйте создать недостающие (до projects) вручную, и создать новый проект. Если не поможет придется переименовать учетку (назвать без точек).

Comment: Сейчас проверю, спасибо

Comment: Вы были правы, спасибо!